# Google Apps Script - Timezones

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the current app script that I have. I want it to return MST Timezone instead of mine.

````
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Task Tracker' && e.range.columnStart == 6 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value) {
    let dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM.dd, YYYY hh:mm a >>");
    e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(e.range.offset(0,-1).getValue() + `\n${dt} ${e.value}`);
    e.range.setValue('');
  }
}```
````

Comment: replace the `Session.getScriptTimeZone()` with this GMT-7

Answer (score 0):

```js
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),"America/Denver","MMM.dd, YYYY hh:mm a >>"));
```

You can try this to get the time converted to the spreadsheet time to the required zone (America/Denver)

---

You can refer to this link it has all the timezones that can be selected
[timezone-id GAS](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/codes-formats#timezone-ids)